# Mostrar tablas y separarlas cada 4

Tags: java, funciones

Tengo que hacer un programa que el usuario diga cuantas tablas de multiplicar quiere que le muestre y yo tengo que mostrarle las tablas de multiplicar en bloque y cada 4 tablas hacer un `println`.
Lo que yo hago es crear un método que me muestre la tabla de multiplicar, pero necesito concatenar el método tabla 4 veces y a la cuarta me haga el `println`
y continúe tantas veces como quiera el usuario.
Las tablas de multiplicar tienen que ser del 1 hasta el numero que diga el usuario.
EL caso es que me sale pero una debajo de la otra y necesito que me salgan 4 en linea y a partir de la 5 abajo y de la 5 a la 8 otra vez en linea y la 9 abajo etc.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Metodes2_E1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        mostrar_taula_sencera(decisio());

    }

    public static void mostrar_taula_sencera(int a) {
        int contador = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
            taula(i);
            contador++;
            if (contador > 4) {
                System.out.println();
                contador = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void mostrar(int a) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++) {
            taula(i);
        }
    }

    public static int decisio() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        System.out.println("Quantes taules de multiplicar vols ?");
        a = sc.nextInt();
        return a;
    }

    public static void taula(int a) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            int aux = a * i;
            System.out.print(a + " x " + i + " = " + aux);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo que deseas es imprimir en bloques de 4, podrías usar la misma clase Scanner para preguntar si desea continuar, si es así puede continuar imprimiendo el siguiente bloque.

Comment: Deberías clarar que las quieres en paralelo... Osea que se muestren en paralelo y cada 4 se baje a la siguiente línea.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar un conteo para imprimir la cantidad de tablas que deseas y usar un do/while para preguntar si  deseas continuar.

```
   public static void taula  (int a) {

        String response="";
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
            int aux=a*i;

            if(counter <= 4){
             System.out.println(a+ " x " +i+" = "+aux);             
            }else{ //Pregunta si desea continuar!

                do{   
                     System.out.println("desea continuar? [S]/[N] \n"); 
                     response= sc.next();
                     counter = 0;
                  }while(!"s".equals(response.toLowerCase()));                             

            }                        
       }        
        counter++; //Contador
    }
```

Este sería un ejemplo completo de acuerdo a tu código :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Metodes2_E1 {

    private static Scanner sc;
    private static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {      
        mostrar(decisio());
    }

    public static void mostrar(int a) {
        for(int i=0;i<=a;i++) {
            taula(i);
        }
    }

    public static int decisio ()  {        
        int a;
        System.out.println("Quantes taules de multiplicar vols ?");
        a=sc.nextInt();
        return a;
    }

   public static void taula  (int a) {

        String response="";
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
            int aux=a*i;

            if(counter <= 4){
             System.out.println(a+ " x " +i+" = "+aux);             
            }else{ //Pregunta si desea continuar!

                do{   
                     System.out.println("desea continuar? [S]/[N] \n"); 
                     response= sc.next();
                     counter = 0;
                  }while(!"s".equals(response.toLowerCase()));                             

            }                        
       }        
        counter++;
    }

}
```

Realizando los cambios anteriores este sería un ejemplo de entrada/salida:

```
Quantes taules de multiplicar vols ?
12
0 x 0 = 0
0 x 1 = 0
0 x 2 = 0
0 x 3 = 0
0 x 4 = 0
0 x 5 = 0
0 x 6 = 0
0 x 7 = 0
0 x 8 = 0
0 x 9 = 0
0 x 10 = 0
1 x 0 = 0
1 x 1 = 1
1 x 2 = 2
1 x 3 = 3
1 x 4 = 4
1 x 5 = 5
1 x 6 = 6
1 x 7 = 7
1 x 8 = 8
1 x 9 = 9
1 x 10 = 10
2 x 0 = 0
2 x 1 = 2
2 x 2 = 4
2 x 3 = 6
2 x 4 = 8
2 x 5 = 10
2 x 6 = 12
2 x 7 = 14
2 x 8 = 16
2 x 9 = 18
2 x 10 = 20
3 x 0 = 0
3 x 1 = 3
3 x 2 = 6
3 x 3 = 9
3 x 4 = 12
3 x 5 = 15
3 x 6 = 18
3 x 7 = 21
3 x 8 = 24
3 x 9 = 27
3 x 10 = 30
4 x 0 = 0
4 x 1 = 4
4 x 2 = 8
4 x 3 = 12
4 x 4 = 16
4 x 5 = 20
4 x 6 = 24
4 x 7 = 28
4 x 8 = 32
4 x 9 = 36
4 x 10 = 40
desea continuar? [S]/[N] 

s
5 x 1 = 5
5 x 2 = 10
5 x 3 = 15
5 x 4 = 20
5 x 5 = 25
5 x 6 = 30
5 x 7 = 35
5 x 8 = 40
5 x 9 = 45
5 x 10 = 50
6 x 0 = 0
6 x 1 = 6
6 x 2 = 12
6 x 3 = 18
6 x 4 = 24
6 x 5 = 30
6 x 6 = 36
6 x 7 = 42
6 x 8 = 48
6 x 9 = 54
6 x 10 = 60
7 x 0 = 0
7 x 1 = 7
7 x 2 = 14
7 x 3 = 21
7 x 4 = 28
7 x 5 = 35
7 x 6 = 42
7 x 7 = 49
7 x 8 = 56
7 x 9 = 63
7 x 10 = 70
8 x 0 = 0
8 x 1 = 8
8 x 2 = 16
8 x 3 = 24
8 x 4 = 32
8 x 5 = 40
8 x 6 = 48
8 x 7 = 56
8 x 8 = 64
8 x 9 = 72
8 x 10 = 80
9 x 0 = 0
9 x 1 = 9
9 x 2 = 18
9 x 3 = 27
9 x 4 = 36
9 x 5 = 45
9 x 6 = 54
9 x 7 = 63
9 x 8 = 72
9 x 9 = 81
9 x 10 = 90
desea continuar? [S]/[N] 

s
10 x 1 = 10
10 x 2 = 20
10 x 3 = 30
10 x 4 = 40
10 x 5 = 50
10 x 6 = 60
10 x 7 = 70
10 x 8 = 80
10 x 9 = 90
10 x 10 = 100
11 x 0 = 0
11 x 1 = 11
11 x 2 = 22
11 x 3 = 33
11 x 4 = 44
11 x 5 = 55
11 x 6 = 66
11 x 7 = 77
11 x 8 = 88
11 x 9 = 99
11 x 10 = 110
12 x 0 = 0
12 x 1 = 12
12 x 2 = 24
12 x 3 = 36
12 x 4 = 48
12 x 5 = 60
12 x 6 = 72
12 x 7 = 84
12 x 8 = 96
12 x 9 = 108
12 x 10 = 120
```

Comment: Esto es lo que me queda pero lo que necesitaria es que en vez de una debajo la otra me ponga cada 4 en paralelo, es decir del 1-4 luego abajo del 5-8 luego abajo del 9-12 etc etc

Comment: Hola Winnie, te refieres a que imprima las primeras 4 así:  0 x 0 = 0 0 x 1 = 0 0 x 2 = 0 .... posteriormente la otras 4 5 x 1 = 5 5 x 2 = 10 5 x 3 = 15 5 x 4 = 20 .... ?

Comment: me refiero a que imprima como tu lo muestras anteriormente pero imagina que la del 1 en vez de estar abajo esta la derecha de la del 0, y la 2 al lado del 1 y la 3 al lado del 2. Y la cuarta ya esta donde estaria en tu ejemplo la tabla del 1, me explico?

Answer (score 0):

En el método main añadimos un bucle para que vaya imprimiendo las tablas y al mismo tiempo las cuente para que cuando lleve 4, imprima un salto de línea con "println"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cantidad = decisio();
    int contador=0;//para contar las tablas que vamos imprimiendo

    for (int i = 1; i <= cantidad; i++) {
        taula(i);//imprimimos una tabla
        contador++;//incrementamos el contador para saber cuantas tablas llevamos

        //si ya tenemos 4 tablas en una línea, imprimimos un cambio de línea
        if (contador==4){
            System.out.println("");// OJO aquí ponemos println acabado en LN
            contador=0;//reseteamos el contador para empezar otra línea
        }            
    }

}
```

En el método taula simplemente cambiamos "println", que añade un cambio de línea cada vez que imprime, por "print", para que lo imprima todo seguido.
Tambien añadimos un separador para que se vea mejor, pero eso ya es simplemente estético.

```
public static void taula(int a) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        int aux = a * i;
        //OJO, en esta impresión utilizamos "print" sin acabar en LN 
        //para que no haga cambio de línea
        System.out.print(a + " x " + i + " = " + aux + "  |  ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias es Justo eso pero, se podría meter en un metodo lo que hay en el main? Te explico tendria que intentar hacelo todo por metodos.Es possible?

Comment: Mete en un método que se llame, por ejemplo "imprimir" la variable "contador" y el bucle "for" y que el método reciba el valor de la variable "cantidad".

Comment: mira modifico mi codigo como lo tengo actualmente pero no me va, me muestra todos en linia no por tablas de multiplicar...